# How to pass stringified JSON as enviorment variable to AWS Lambda (Using GUI)

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass stringified JSON an env var to AWS Lambda, but I can't parse it back.

It works locally (VSCode, Windows), but fails on AWS.

It looks as follow:
`{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"hello\":\"world\"}`

Passing it through ENV var on launch.json in VSCode works, but fails when I pass it on Lambda.

`Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 0`
And if I log the value it got from the ENV I see that it replace every `\` with `\\`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is because you try to copy the value from VSCode debugging tool instead of the actual string.
VSCode adds those `\` so the stringified JSON could be used as string inside VSCode without `"` character causing issues.

The actual stringified JSON should look like `{"foo":"bar","hello":"world"}`